# How to reference the current entry via twig in the control panel?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel

I'm trying to write a general use plugin for a calculation fieldtype that evaluates a twig expression (defined in the field settings) to display additional information about the current record in the CP (i.e. price * qty = amount). So far, everything is working perfectly — the generic expression `1 + 1` is evaluated and the result is properly displayed in the field.

The problem is, I don't actually know how to reference the current entry in the CP from within the CP via twig, to get access to the entry field values. Looking for something like `{{ entry.price }} * {{ entry.qty }}`, but don't know what to use instead of `entry`. Does anyone know a twig expression that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know. The variable {{ entry }} is not available to custom field plugins through inheritance and must be explicitly set and returned as a variable in the `getInputHtml` method within the class definition file.

See [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/how-to-reference-the-current-entry-element-in-custom-control-panel-templates/4266?noredirect=1#comment4699_4266) for details on how to set this variable and things to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hard to tell what's going on without any code examples, but if you're just looking for a way to grab an entry from your plugin, and you already have the ID of the entry, then [EntriesService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/EntriesService) has a [getEntryById()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/EntriesService#getEntryById-detail) method available via `craft()->entries->getEntryById()` that your plugin can call.

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The plugin is designed to just evaluate a twig expression, and output the result into the field. Within the plugin settings you can define the twig expression to be evaluated. Something like {{ entry.unitPrice * entry.quantity }}. The problem is {{entry}} does not seem to work in this context. I'm looking for a way to reference the current entry within the admin panel. I don't know if there is already a variable defined for this, or if I should create a custom 'entry' or 'id' variable in the plugin, or if I should parse the uri within the twig expression to retrieve the id.